# ssh-config by host subnet

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I have a whole bunch of machines on my **10.10.10.x** subnet, all of them are essentially configured in the same way. I differentiate these from machines on my **10.10.11.x** subnet which serves a different purpose.

I'd like to be able to type `ssh 10.x` to connect to machines on the **10.x** network and `ssh 11.x` to connect to machines on the **11.x** network.

I know I can set up individual machines to allow access to the full IP, or the shorthand version like this in my *~/.ssh/config*:

```
Host 10.10.10.11 10.11
HostName 10.10.10.11
User root
```

This can get pretty repetitive for lots of hosts on my network, so my question is: Is there a way to specify this as a pattern for the entire subnet? Something like:

```
Host 10.10.10.x
User root

Host 10.x
HostName 10.10.10.x
User root
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This line will provide the desired functionality:

```
Host 192.168.1.*
IdentityFile KeyFile
```

If you attempt to connect a server whose ip is in this subnet, you will be able to establish an ssh connection.

Comment: This basically works how I want, but is there a way you can access the '*' part, for example my use case above of wanting to map a certain range into a HostName by pattern?

Comment: I had to use 'Host 192.168.1.?' instead in OS X

Comment: I've got this to work when connecting to IPs, but not when connecting to a hostname in that subnet. Is this supposed to work when using hostnames to connect?

Comment: doesn't work if host from subnet accessed by its hostname

Answer (score 15):

From the `ssh_config(5)` Manpage:

```
 A pattern consists of zero or more non-whitespace characters, ‘*’ (a
 wildcard that matches zero or more characters), or ‘?’ (a wildcard that
 matches exactly one character).  For example, to specify a set of decla‐
 rations for any host in the “.co.uk” set of domains, the following pat‐
 tern could be used:

       Host *.co.uk

 The following pattern would match any host in the 192.168.0.[0-9] network
 range:

       Host 192.168.0.?

 A pattern-list is a comma-separated list of patterns.  Patterns within
 pattern-lists may be negated by preceding them with an exclamation mark
 (‘!’).  For example, to allow a key to be used from anywhere within an
 organisation except from the “dialup” pool, the following entry (in
 authorized_keys) could be used:

       from="!*.dialup.example.com,*.example.com"
```

So you can just use `host 10.*`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22090363/241211#comment40804769_22090363) about mapping:

> This basically works how I want, but is there a way you can access the `*` part, for example my use case above of wanting to map a certain range into a `HostName` by pattern?

…Which you can accomplish with [tokens](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/openssh-client/ssh_config.5.en.html#TOKENS). In your case, use `%h`  to replace a part of the `HostName` with the `Host` value.

I have changed the match pattern to use `?`s instead of `*`s to constrain the length of the matched segment. This avoids some confusion wherein `10.*` also matches `10.10.10.x`. Technically, you can add an explicit `HostName` to the 4-octet IPs' `Host` blocks and make sure they occur before the shortcut blocks, but using `?` is more foolproof.

Put blocks like these into your *~/.ssh/config* alongside your full IP configuration:

```bash
Host 10.? 10.?? 10.1??
    HostName 10.10.%h
    # Your parameters here.

Host 11.? 11.?? 11.1??
    HostName 10.10.%h
    # Your parameters here.
```

Or, if you want to keep the config for `10.10.10.x` centralized with the config for `10.x`, you can tell SSH to convert the hostname and take another pass through the config document, like this:

```bash
# Both patterns can be combined into one block here because they share
# the same `HostName` stem and the differing config is set elsewhere.
Host 10.? 10.?? 10.1?? 11.? 11.?? 11.1??
    HostName 10.10.%h
    CanonicalizeHostname yes

Host 10.10.10.*
    # Your parameters here.

Host 10.10.11.*
    # Your parameters here.
```